# Google App Engine: How do i configure it to send some resources as zipped to save bandwidth?

Tags: google-app-engine, gzip

Some of the static resources on my web apps would benefit if they are sent zipped 
(http compression)
For instance I have some very large .js (javascript) files.

The js files have been minified yet they are still large and gzipping them would help.

Does anybody how to do this ?

I am using google app engine java version

Answer (score 7, accepted):

App engine will automatically gzip the responses so long as the client sends the appropriate HTTP headers (specifically `Accept-Encoding` and `User-Agent`) that indicate it can accept compressed content. See [this](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#Responses) for more information.

Comment: thanks for this. That does answer my question. Do you happen to know though how I can verify that it works that way ?

Comment: You can use the [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) extension for Firefox to examine request and response headers.